# Javascript function that calculates based on increments

Tags: javascript, loops

I need assistance creating a javascript function that performs the below logic.

If cubic ft is between 2500-5000 invoice $42, but if greater than 5000 then invoice $42 plus $22 per 1000 cubic ft.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var assessfee = function(cubicft) { 
    if (cubicft > 2500 || cubicft <= 5000) {
       console.log($42);
    } else if (cubicft > 5000) {
       var diff = cubicft - 5000;

    }
}
```

Comment: So now divide `diff` by 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Basically that sets the price to 42 since that is the default price and if cubicft is > 5000 it takes that divided by 1000 then takes it times 22 and adds that value to price. Finally it prints it to the console.

```
var assessfee = function(cubicft) { 
    var price = 42;
    if (cubicft > 5000) {
        price += (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
    }
    console.log("$" + price);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie!  How can do I modify the if statement so it does not start adding the additional $22 until cubicft is greater than 5000.  Currently, it adds every 1000 cubic ft increment.

Comment: var assessfee = function(cubicft) { 
    var price = 42;
    if (cubicft > 5000) {
        price += (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
    }
    console.log("$" + price);
}

Comment: @coop Should be yeah.

Comment: How can I add an if else condition so that price equals 42 if cubicft are between 2500-5000 or price equals 0 if less than 2500 cubic ft?

Comment: This is what I have so far.  function updateFireFee(cubicft) {
    var price = 42;
    if (cubicft > 2500 || cubicft <= 5000) {
     price = 42;
    }
    else if (cubicft > 5000) {
        price += (cubicft-5000)/1000*22;
    } else {
     price = 0;
    }
 
}

Comment: @coop That sounds like a new question. I'm not quite sure what you are asking or anything. I would probably ask a new question.